# Is there a way to unit test an Android app's label text?

Tags: android, robolectric

I'd like to write a unit test to assert that my Android app's label (that is displayed on the launcher screen under the app icon).

```
<application
        android:name=".FinanceApplication"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/application_title" // <-- I want to test this field
>     

// …
</application>
```

My project is already using Robolectric to write unit tests. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just write test that reads xml and check value there. In addition you could write test that checks your string value has correct value but it is actually testing correct translations which I would not do at all

Comment: @Prairiedogg . Please share a few snippets on how you have achieved the assertion on the label attribute. Tried  the following . 1.RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationInfo().labelRes but always return 0 . 2. Application Info from the PackageManager.  It didn't work.